# ASP.NET 4.0 Database Created Pages

Tags: asp.net, database, data-driven

I want to create ASP.NET 4.0 dynamic pages loaded from my MS SQL server. Basically, it's a list of locations with information. For example:

```
Location1 would have the page www.site.com/location/location1.aspx
Location44 would have the page www.site.com/location/location44.aspx
```

I don't even know where to start with this, URL rewriting maybe?

Comment: Need more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url rewriting addresses a different problem than what you are describing.

You can use an HttpHandler that handles requests to the path `location` and parse the last segment to get your lookup key then simply pass execution off to an .aspx. Although you are passing execution off to a general page, the url will remain as entered.

I will provide an example. Give it a shot. [here is a sample project](http://skysanders.net/files/StackOverflow/DBHandler.zip)

**LocationHandler.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace DBHandler
{
    public class LocationHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            string page = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(request.Url.Segments[request.Url.Segments.Length - 1]);

            // for url ~/location/location33.aspx page will be 'location33'

            // do something interesting with page, perhaps 
            context.Server.Execute("~/locations.aspx?locationId=" + context.Server.UrlEncode(page));
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**locations.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Request["locationId"];
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.config excerpt**

```
...
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="location/*.*" type="DBHandler.LocationHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
...
```